# Change fonts in my StatusStripLabel

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010

I use the following code to change the parameters in my StatuStripLabel

```
Dim ItemImage As System.Drawing.Image = iImage
    Dim item = New ToolStripStatusLabel(sText, ItemImage)
    item.BorderSides = ToolStripStatusLabelBorderSides.All
    item.BorderStyle = Border3DStyle.RaisedOuter
    item.LinkBehavior = LinkBehavior.HoverUnderline

    item.IsLink = True
    StatusStrip2.Items.Add(item)
```

Now is there anybody to assist me in changing the fonts and fonts size?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
item.Font = new System.Drawing.Font("YOUR_FONT_NAME", 9F, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Regular, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point, ((byte)(0)));
```

Comment: Your Answer is grate thanks, but tell me please in the second parameter why we type 9F? and what is this size?

Comment: You're welcome. It's used to indicate that we're using a double float number. (f or F can be used.)